# Sending Email on Form Submission After Gathering Data from A Different Spreadsheet

Tags: forms, email, google-sheets

I need some help fixing my current code. Here is what I am trying to do:
1. Have user submit a Google form (name, class, etc.)
2. Take those answers and search a separate spreadsheet for matching information (same name, class, etc.)
3. Return data from the same row the matching data is found in (parents name, email, etc.)
4. Send an email to the parents containing information from the original Google form

I think where I have mistakes is the part of the ode that attempts to open the separate sheet by ID and search and return values. I've included this section of the code below.

Does anyone have any suggestions? All are welcome! And thank you for your time :)

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17aA0SMZe1tarCUWM0ROdFmGoE3xsqrFRtYviHb85cqM");
Logger.log(sh.getName());
var sheet = sh.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = dataRange.getValues();

for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
{return values[i][7];}

var primaryContactFirstName = values[i][7];

if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
{return values[i][8];}

var primaryContactLastName = values[i][8];

if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
{return values[i][9];}

var primaryContactEmail = values[i][9];}


if(dancersFirstName + dancersLastName + class == values[i][0] + values[i][1] + values[i][2], toEmailAddress = primaryContactEmail);
```

The entire code is as follows:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var timestamp = e.values[0];

  var dancersFirstName = e.values[1];

  var dancersLastName = e.values[2];

  var class = e.values[3];

  var teacher = e.values[4]

  var attentiveness = e.values[5]

  var bodyPlacement = e.values[6];

  var memory = e.values[7];

  var corrections = e.values[8];

  var performance = e.values[9];

  var attendance = e.values[10];

  var comments = e.values[11];

  var placement = e.values[12];

  var teachersEmailAddress = e.values[13];

  var toEmailAddress = teachersEmailAddress;



  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().openbyID("17aA0SMZe1tarCUWM0ROdFmGoE3xsqrFRtYviHb85cqM");
  var values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
    {return values[i][7];}

    var primaryContactFirstName = values[i][7];

   if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
    {return values[i][8];}

    var primaryContactLastName = values[i][8];

   if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class)
    {return values[i][9];}

   var primaryContactEmail = values[i][9]; 

    if(dancersFirstName + dancersLastName + class == values[i][0] + values[i][1] + values[i][2], toEmailAddress = primaryContactEmail);}



  var subject = "2015-2016 Evaluation & Placement";

  var emailBody = "Dear" + dancersFirstName + " " + dancersLastName + " "+ "and" + primaryContactFirstName +" " + primaryContactLastName + " " +

  "Below is your dancer's evaluation and pleacement for" + class +

  "\n\nIs this dancer focused and attentive in class?" + attentiveness +

  "\n\nDoes this dancer understand and work towards correct body placement and alignment?" + bodyPlacement +

  "\n\nHas this dancer mastered the steps taught this year?  Is the dancer able to remember combinations?" + memory +

  "\n\nIs this dancer able to apply corrections?" + corrections +

  "\n\nIs this dancer able to dance with the music, perform with confidence, and display a commitment to performance quality?" + performance +

  "\n\nHas this dancer attended class regularly?" + attendance +

  "\n\nAdditonal Comments:" + comments +

  "\n\nPlacement for next year:" + placement +

  "\n\nThank you for dancing with us and enjoy your summer!" + teacher + "and The Moving Company Dance Center";

  MailApp.sendEmail(toEmailAddress,subject,emailBody);}
```

Comment: is this the incomplete body of a function? This script by itself makes little sense, you do the same check three times each time returning something in what appears to be the global environment and finally do another if clause that has a second argument but no result.

Comment: I've included the entire code in the question in above. i wasn't sure if i can return three values as once, which is why I repeated the same check 3 times (I'm pretty novice at writing code). at the end i was trying to do a final check to make sure that the name and class submitted on the form is the same as the one in selected in the spreadsheet.

do you know of a way to do this properly? I've been trying to figure it out for awhile and have tried different thing but haven't really gotten anywhere :/

Comment: When you return it exits the function, nothing in the body of the code after the return statement is executed. Just put all the assignment statements inside the then body of the if clause

Comment: thank you so much for your response and help! i changed the if clause like you said.

however, emails are still not being sent. do you have any other suggestions?

I've included the new if clause in the comment below

Comment: for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if(values[i][0] == dancersFirstName && values[i][1] == dancersLastName && values[i][2] == class && values[i][4] == teacher)
    {var primaryContactFirstName = values[i][7]
    var primaryContactLastName = values[i][8]
    var primaryContactEmail = values[i][9]
    var toEmailAddress = primaryContactEmail;}